# How to store the sum of two integers into a long variable in C?

Tags: c

I created a matrix of ints for example have {1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5}
and then I'm trying  to store the sum of the matrix into a long variable:

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define m 5
int main (){
    int i;
    int matrix[m];
    long matrix_sum;

    for(i = 0; i < m ; i++)  //filling the matrix
        matrix[i] = matrix[i-1]+1;

    for(i = 0; i < m ; i++)  //adding ints to long
        matrix_sum += matrix[i];

    printf("%lo \n",matrix_sum);
    return 0;
}
```

when I run this code I have "17" on output instead of "15" !!

Comment: `matrix[i-1]` is undefined behavior for `i` == `0`.

Comment: `matrix_sum` is used without initialization, too.

Comment: Incidentally, 15 is 17 in octal.

Answer (score 4):

Think about what happens on the first iteration of this loop:

```
for(i = 0; i < m ; i++)  //filling the matrix
    matrix[i] = matrix[i-1]+1;
```

Notice that you'll be reading from index -1 of this array (oops!) This leads to *undefined behavior*, which means that in principle *anything* can happen. Your program could get garbage data, get the wrong answer, or even outright crash!

It's up to you to decide how to avoid this case. Consider changing the loop indices so that you start at a higher index.

Also, look at the remaining variables in `main`. Are they initialized? If not, adding values to them will again result in undefined behavior and pretty much anything can happen to them.

Finally, look at how you're `printf`ing things:

```
printf("%lo \n",matrix_sum);
```

The `%lo` specifier means "the argument is a `long`, and it should be printed in octal (base-8)." This means that you're not printing the value in decimal, so even if you'd expect to get the value 15<sub>dec</sub>, you'd instead see 17, the octal representation of the number.

Comment: Or initialise with just `matrix[i] = i+1;`, which is a lot clearer.

Comment: Logically I should have undefined behaviour with  matrix[i]=matrix [i-1]+1;  , but I dont.  Thanks for the answer bro it's helpfull

Answer (score 2):

I have not seen a matrix. It seems you mean an array or a vector.

For starters according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

The variable `matrix_sum` was not initialized.

In this loop

```
for(i = 0; i < m ; i++)  //filling the matrix
matrix[i] = matrix[i-1]+1;
                   ^^^^
```

there is an attempt to access memory beyond the array when the variable `i` is equal to 0.

And it looks like you wanted to use the conversion specifier `%ld` in this statement

```
printf("%lo \n",matrix_sum);
        ^^^
```

Otherwise the output will be as an octal number.

I think you mean the following. At least the program output is exactly equal to 15.:)

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N   5

int main(void) 
{
    int a[N];
    int i;
    long sum;

    for ( i = 0; i < N ; i++ ) a[i] = i + 1;

    sum = 0;
    for ( i = 0; i < N ; i++ ) sum += a[i];

    printf( "%ld\n", sum );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Logically I shoud have undefined behaviour but I don't. Thanks  for answering I got this finally

Comment: @baraa - you **do** have undefined behavior. Just because on one system the initial value of an out-of-bounds array element is zero doesn't mean the behavior is "defined". "Undefined behavior" simply means that on a different machine, with a different compiler, you *may* get garbage instead of zero. Even if you do get zero on all machines with all compilers currently in use, the behavior is still undefined: I may write a new compiler tomorrow where the initial value is -1, and that would still conform to the Standard.